# Storing elements inside a custom array ( Casting help)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I parse my XML(root tag -- "Registry") and store in a object of type Registry.
Eg:
XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Registry>
    <Schools>
        <School loc= "XXX">
            <Student name = "XXX"/>
            <Student name = "XX1"/>
            <Student name = "XX2"/>
        </School>
        
        <School loc= "YYY">
            <Student name = "XXX"/>
            <Student name = "XY1"/>
            <Student name = "XY2"/>
        </School>
        
        <School loc= "ZZZ">
            <Student name = "YXX"/>
            <Student name = "YX1"/>
            <Student name = "YX2"/>
        </School>
        
        <School loc= "AAA">
            <Student name = "ZXX"/>
            <Student name = "ZX1"/>
            <Student name = "ZX2"/>
        </School>
        
    </Schools>
</Registry>
```

The XML is unmarshalled as below and stored in the object of root tag type.

```
File xmlFile = new File("studteachobjmodel.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext;
jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Registry .class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Registry xmlentries = (Registry) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);
```

Now if i have a series of such XML files, I declare an array object of type `Registry[] xmlentries`
I want to store the XML entries in the array of the *Registry* Type. I have done the following, but it shows an error

```
    Registry[]xmlentries = null;
    JAXBContext jaxbContext;
    File dir = new File("XMLFiles");
    if (dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {
        FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {
                @Override
                public boolean accept(File file) {
                    return file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".xml");
                }
            };
        File [] files = dir.listFiles(filter);
        if (files != null) {                    
                for (int i =0;i <files.length;i++) {    
                    jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Registry.class);
                    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                    xmlentries[i] = (Registry) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(files[i]); //ERROR
                    
                }
            }
        
        }
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot store to object array because "xmlentries" is null
    at code.GenerateXML.main(GenerateXML.java:31)
```

Any hint to overcome this please.
TIA

Comment: Which line is 31?

Comment: The error line in the image#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialize your array `xmlentries`.

```
Registry[] xmlentries = null;
```

So when you try to assign an object to it here

```
xmlentries[i] = (Registry) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(files[i]);
```

it will throw a `NullPointerException`.

You should either use a `List`, a `Set` or intialize your array if you absolutely want an array

`Registry[] xmlentries = new Registry[10];` (for an array of 10 elements for instance).

or if you want an array of the size of your number of files

```
    [...]
    File [] files = dir.listFiles(filter);
    if (files != null) {  
            xmlentries = new Registry[files.length]; <-- intialization of your array here                  
            for (int i = 0;i < files.length;i++) {    
    [...]
```

However, I would suggest you to use a `Set` (if you want unique entries) or a `List` (if you want order), it's easier to manipulate than an array.

```
Set<Registry> entries = new Hashet<>();
List<Registry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thanks Pilpo. I used the list and got it working